# Uri Can't be assigned to webUri

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//this is the package which allows in app web browser view feature
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:loading_animation_widget/loading_animation_widget.dart';
import 'package:project1_test/pages/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:project1_test/theme/Textstyle.dart';
import 'package:project1_test/theme/colors.dart';
class forgotpass extends StatefulWidget {
const forgotpass({super.key});
@override
State<forgotpass> createState() => _forgotpassState();}
class _forgotpassState extends State<forgotpass> {
InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
bool isLoading = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
elevation: 0,
backgroundColor: //use any color here,
title: Text( 'Forgot Password',style: Colors.white,),
centerTitle: true,
actions: [
TextButton(child: Text(
          'LOGIN',
          style:Colors.white,
        ),
 onPressed: () {Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loginPage()));
        },), ], ),
body: Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
children: [ Expanded( child: Stack(
children: [ InAppWebView(
initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
//this is where i am getting the error
 url: Uri.parse('Any Url that will open in the inappwbview'),),
onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
 webViewController = controller; },
onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
setState(() { isLoading = true; });
},
onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
setState(() {
isLoading = false;});
}, ),
if (isLoading)
Center(
child: LoadingAnimationWidget.beat(color: purpleColor, size: 50),
)
],
 ))
],
),
);
} }
```

I'm encountering a type mismatch error in my Flutter app while using the InAppWebView widget. The specific error message is: The argument type 'UriData' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'WebUri?' the same code is working in a different application with a different url but its not working for me this code is suppose to open a in-app browser display the webpage enter image description here

if the error is fixed and once tapped on forgot password button... the app should take me to a password reset web page but in a in app web browser

Comment: Please post your code not as a screenshot. And it seems like you have a type mismatch as the error says. You need to create a WebUri variable.

Comment: i have added the code kindly have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `url` is a string variable holding an url string, you can do something like this:

`WebUri webUrl = WebUri.uri(UriData.fromString(url).uri);`

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thank you, i did what you just said but i think i only got rid of the error... on tapping the button instead of showing the content on the link it shows the link on  a white screen.......

Comment: I think that's an issue with the link you have. I used this code for a login page and it successfully loaded.

Comment: thanks.... Currently its happening to all that i am trying none of them are loading]