Flutter inappwebview does not load
I'm working to implement inappwebview from flutter_inappwebview package. But when run the following code it only display string of url on my screen.
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(children: [
        SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri.uri(UriData.fromString("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77757847/uri-cant-be-assigned-to-weburi").uri)), // test
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                inAppWebViewController = controller;
              },
              onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                setState(() {
                  _progress = progress / 100;
                });
              },
            )),


I would like to open a webview inside my website and fetch url changes on it.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Refer this file for the package you have used InAppWebViewExample.dart

Thank you for your comment. I seen that document but I couldn’t understand it. So I watched YouTube video and this was minimum model that was functional. Please at lease help me understand what I’m lacking.
